# Federal Rules of Procedure - Multi-jurisdictional local rules

Tags: civil-procedure, rules-of-court, reference-request

Has anyone anyone ever come across a full set of the complete Federal Rules that also contains an indexed version of every jurisdiction's local rules? I looked last year and I know the big 2 didn't offer this as they'd prefer you buy each state individually, but  it occurred to me that maybe something else might be out there I haven't heard of. I have found that in some states the local rules are so different that it would be impossible to navigate a federal case without having become quite familiar with the local rules, and I do not like to rely on my co-counsel for adherence; especially if they are not involved on a material level (knowing the requirement that local counsel must co-counsel a federal action if one is not licensed in that jurisdiction and appearing *pro hoc vice*). I am aware this is available online but do not want to print and need/want a hard copy.

Comment: You mention that is is available online - can you let me know where? I ask because while the logistics of printing every rule update would be an incredible feat, being the central repository of every state's rules would be a task in and of itself.

Comment: Oh ya, just like lexis or west law both have complete compilation

Comment: And I think, by way of free, findlaw has it all too

Comment: The D.C. District's local rules are 202 pages long. There are 94 U.S. District Courts. Such volume would be ungainly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of anyone who offers all of the local rules in a single printed volume, but Thomson Reuters sells softbound Court rules sets for each state: Generally one volume of state rules, a volume of "Key Rules", and a volume of federal rules that contain the local rules that apply in that state. Local rules in state courts are often not published in a printed form.

Comment: Ya, I get them for each state I'm admitted in or regularly appear *pro hac vice*, but they're super expensive and it'd surely be cheaper if someone compiled a multi-state. I like having the paper books while in court, even though I have them all on Lexis/west. Thanks though :-)

Comment: Have your paralegal go to the websites and print them all out and put them in binders (or save them in pdf form so that you can use them in court without being connected ti the Internet) and repeat the process once every year or two. I do something similar with Medicaid regulations and Marijuana regulations in Colorado. Or, better than binders, make the pdfs and then have Kinkos bind several volumes for you which is surprisingly cheap and very professional looking.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a waste of time, especially given procedural rules are constantly changing -  whatever you had would be outdated in a short time

Note, Where fed court (district) (in that state) are located controls procedural fundamentals of that fed courts rules and rulings (as a rule of thumb)  - like Texas, (for example) I think Texas requires verification of a complaint (verified complaints)  thus, same in that fed dist court - whereas Washington State does not require verified complaints, therefore, the fed dist court located in Washington does not require verified complaints - plus, see rule 3002 that denotes the federal courts must follow state law - as such, whatever state a federal district court is located controls (again generally speaking) that court's federal ruling or procedures  - Constitutional issue still stand as controlling state or feds -

Comment: Well that's sort of the point... As with all rule books, amended volumes or "pocket parts", get issued annually. For a multi-jurisdictional practitioner would be invaluable.